# Sunspot fulltext search with OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot

I have the Rails project with User model.
It has two fields: `:name`, `:surname`
Also I have sunset search:

```
searchable do
  text :name
  text :surname
end
```

When I do such search:
`User.solr_search { fulltext 'Name Surname' } .results`
how to get results all results in such order:

1. where name and surname are `'Name Surname'`
2. where only surname is `'Surname'`
3. where only name is `'Name'`

Also I found, but I don't understand is that what I need
https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Matching-substrings-in-fulltext-search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boosters, so that surname results come before name results and surname&name results before surname results.

```
searchable do
    text :surname, boost: 2.0
    text :name,    boost: 1.0
end
```

You ask any term to be matched and then order them descendingly on score. Results matching name and surname will score higher, only surname lower and only name lowest.

```
@search=User.search
    fulltext "#{name_variable} #{surname_variable}", :minimum_match => 1
    order_by(:score, :desc)
end
```